# How do I unit test web app which reads from files stored in project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

In my application I am reading XML files stored in a directory in the project.

My tests run fine when I specify the absolute path to the files in my app but they break when I use ***relative paths***.

When I look at where the test is failing the path looks like this:

`C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\NCrunch\9824\11\ElectionScoreboard.Tests\bin\Debug\ElectionScoreboard.DataLayer\ElectionResults\AllResults\result001.xml`

> **Note:** I am using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to construct the path to the file

I've done some Googling & looked into the possibility of using a `TestContext` but I'm not sure how to do this - can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you're changing the path in the app, not in the tests?

**Unit** tests should never go past a certain scope (the unit, generally a class). In other words, you shouldn't touch the DB/read files - that's already system (integration testing).

Your unit test should rather just test the logic around that file read whilst mocking the layer handling the actual file read.

Otherwise, if you want to go down the **system** test path, you would have to issue a request towards the url (port number & all) your web app resides, not through a direct reference to it.

Only wrote this as an answer because it's too long for a comment, you'll need to provide more details if you need specific answers.